# how to add css in page designer

Tags: css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have some page items, 3 IR regions and buttons in a form on apex5.0.
How is it possible to write and attach a css files to make all these components,

Page Item      : font-style: italic; font: Verdana
Regions        : columns dark blue with grey background color for the header
Data in regions: black font
font-size      : medium
Button         : Dark Grey with black font

Is it possible to write a common css class or shall css class and attributes be added to each specific PI, Region & button.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

On every page you have CSS section. One is for **File URLs** and other is for **Inline** .In case you have files you can add URL in files section or provide link from other servers. You can upload css files in **Application-> Shared Components-> Files**
In inline section you can add CSS directly. To customize some of your region or butons you can add **Static id** in **Advanced->Static ID** and use id like:

```
#regionID{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: fixed;
top: 0em;
right: 0em;
background-size: 10%;
}
```

You can use some of the Apex classes or add your custom class and style many items at once

```
.someClass{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
background-size: 160px 230px;
}
```

Other option is to use Theme Roller from Developer Toolbar. In section Custom CSS you can add inline code also.